# Como exibir os dados do MYSQL em Value dentro do input

Tags: php, html, mysql

Este é meu código PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM config WHERE id IN (1,2,3)");
$sdda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Este é o HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>About Text:</label> <i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Player About Text"></i>
    <input type="text" name="filmes" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sdda['id(x)'];; ?>">

  </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber como consigo exibir o dado de apenas uma id, como por exemplo a id = 2 no `value`, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não faltou um `echo` ali? E não está muito claro o problema. Se precisa apenas do valor referente ao id 2, por que você seleciona os ids 1 e 3?

Comment: perdão na pergunta sim, porem gostaria de exibir os dados que estão na tabela, porem apenas o de cada id, o codigo esta todo em html mesmo, fiz uma referencia em html in php

Comment: Você quer que seja exibido um text pra cada filme ou todos no mesmo text? Ainda não entendi isso.

Comment: quase isso, na tabela possui 2 colunas, id e a config, eu gostaria que seja exigido como por exemplo o id 2 e a config do height, eu gostaria de exibir ela na caixa

Comment: Leandro, para acessar uma posição do array vc tem usar um inteiro entre os colchetes, assim $array[3]. se id(x) for um método, ele tem que retornar um inteiro ou algo que possa ser um inteiro. Se vc tiver um método id(), por favor compartilhe.